# not able to store the data to mongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying since 3 hours to store the data from html form to mongodb using noddejs.
while clicking on submit it shows another page which returns the data which has been submitted in json format but it is not being stored in database.

This is my app.js:

```
app.use(serveStatic(__dirname+"/index.html")).listen(8080);

var mongoUri = 'mongodb://localhost/test';
```

//Note that I am changing the dbname and trying to store data in different //db will also shows the same error

```
mongoose.connect(mongoUri);

var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', function () {
  throw new Error('unable to connect to database at ' + mongoUri);
});

console.log("connection successfull");
app.use(express.bodyParser());


app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/" ));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));

app.post('/InquiryDetails', function(req,res){

    res.json(req.body);
    console.log(req.body);

});
require('./models/InquiryDetails');

app.listen(4000);
console.log('Listening on port 4000...');
```

this is my model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var myskyllSchema = new Schema({
  name: String, 
  email: String,
  state: String,
  country: String,
  school: String,
  profession: String,
  phone: Number
});

mongoose.model('InquiryDetails', myskyllSchema);
```

This is my controller:

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
InquiryDetails = mongoose.model('InquiryDetails');


exports.add = function(req, res) {
  InquiryDetails.create(req.body, function (error, details) {
    if (error) return console.log(error); 
    return res.send(details);
  });
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't look like you ever connected to the database since there is no `mongoose.connect(mongoUri)` anywhere. Also your "controller" code does not appear to be "wired" into any action. All based on the code listed here

Comment: Maybe but you didn't pay attention to the second part of the comment. Look at your code after here: `app.post('/InquiryDetails', function(req,res){`. Does not call your `.add` method from the other module. It just does .. what did you say was happening again?

Comment: @NeilLunn he is using express which allows you to export certain function names and express will call them according to your route look at https://github.com/strongloop/express/tree/master/examples/mvc

Comment: @gabeio I think I would know that. But you clearly are not seeing the obvious mistake. Read the statement at the start of the question and then read the code right after the line I mentioned. .

Comment: @NeilLunn he is "calling" it by importing it `require('./models/InquiryDetails');`

Comment: @gotchha but I believe you need to use `exports.create` and pass the request through that call by using the `next()` command

Comment: @gabeio It doesn't work like that. You can ony "import" from an "export" and it still "needs" to be bound to the "post" action. It is not. and the only code there is `res.json(reb.body)`, which is exactly what is happening here.

Comment: @NeilLunn I have added the add() method in post() now it showing that `Schema hasn't been registered for model "InquiryDetails". ` where i already registered it .

Comment: @gotchha Bit of advice. I have this problem... Oh thanks I fixed that .. Now I have this new problem!. That is what you are saying here. One question, one answer. You forgot to alter your code and left it just echoing the json. That was you question. You should close this question and ask another with the spefic problem you are encountering now.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the code in app.js :

`app.post('/InquiryDetails', function(req, res) {
     InquiryDetails.create(req.body, function (error, details) {
       if (error) return console.log(error);
       return res.send(details);
       res.send(req.body);
     });
   });`

instead of :

`exports.add = function(req, res) {
        InquiryDetails.create(req.body, function (error, details) {
        if (error) return console.log(error); 
        return res.send(details);
     });
   }`

The reason is controller was unable to load and method add is not registered with post method. Now it is working.